# SQL - Selecting all rows with non matching null rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, window-functions, sql-null

How can I select all rows which have a non matching null row? Given the following table, any row with the foreign key 1 should not be returned since a corresponding row with a NULL exists. How could I only select rows with the foreign keys 2 and 3?

```
foreign_key | created_at
1             12345...
1             12345...
2             12345...
3             12345...
1             NULL
```

Comment: Did you try to `SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE created_at IS NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select *
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.foreign_key = t.foreign_key and t1.created_at is null
)
```

Another option is to use window functions; here is one approach using boolean windowing:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, bool_or(created_at is null) over(partition by foreignkey) has_null
    from mytable t
) t
where not has_null
```